# Why does sorting an array with a fixed length (such as an array with only five elements) cost O(1)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

It is my understanding that when n is fixed, the cost of sorting n elements is O(1).

For example, in this explanation of the linear-time median finding algorithm, it says:

```
# Next, we sort each chunk. Each group is a fixed length, so each sort
# takes constant time. Since we have n/5 chunks, this operation
# is also O(n)
```

https://rcoh.me/posts/linear-time-median-finding/

I don't understand why. Am I supposed to imagine that there is a function that covers all possible 5! combinations of how the elements are positioned?

Comment: Sure. Is that a difficult thing to imagine?

Comment: A sorting algorithm can in the best case be O(n) (if the collection is already sorted). If n is constant then the best-case scenario is also done in constant time which is commonly expressed as O(1).

Comment: It does not have to be a 1-step-operation. Sorting the fixed-length sub-arrays can take 10 or 20 steps, but if it can never take more than 20 steps, it's still O(1).

Comment: @Sneftel What I'm trying to ask is how does that make sense? If I can say it for 5 then I can say it for a million. Why does just saying "the n is fixed" change sorting one trillion elements from O(nlogn) to O(1)? Seems misleading...

Comment: Big O notation is always contingent on an understanding of how we measure the size of the input, and what counts as a step. Yes, an algorithm that sorts a trillion elements can be called O(1). It just has either completely unreasonable storage demands (by consulting an impossibly huge lookup table (like, seriously, exceeds-the-size-of-the-universe-big)), or else the "constant" hidden by the O(1) notation is unreasonably huge. Big O notation is an abstraction, a tool, and it *can* be misleading if not applied with reason.

Comment: The important bit in the cited material is the fact that we the sorting is considered O(1) in the context of having 5 chunks of a bigger, n-sized collection. Within that context, it is not unreasonable to say that each chunk is sorted in O(1). Alternatively, and perhaps more clear, you could say it takes 5 * O(n/5), which of course is still just O(n) in total.

Comment: @SándorDés You can say it for a trillion, sure. Congratulations, you've got an O(1) algorithm. But it's not a complete sort function for arbitrary arrays, because it can't sort anything with more than one trillion elements.

Comment: @JeroenMostert "Within that context, it is not unreasonable to say the each chunk is sorted in O(1)" I am confused by this. When analyzing algorithms, is it common practice to consider the sorting of small arrays O(1) just because in practice it has a small runtime?

Comment: No, it's common (and correct) to consider the sorting of fixed-size arrays to be O(1) because it takes a bounded amount of time. "Small" doesn't really come into it.

Comment: Well, you _could_ have an algorithm that takes chunks of 1 trillion elements an sorts those in "O(1)" time, but the _general_ complexity of the overall algorithm (including partitioning the list into those groups, merging the groups, etc.) would still be O(nlogn) or something like that for lists with a quadrillion elements.

Comment: If this didn't already have a good answer, btw, I'd be suggesting it move to [cs.se], where it's more clearly on-topic. Stack Overflow's area of focus is *writing code*; analyzing code's runtime behavior is outside of that.

Comment: @SándorDés Two points are **O()** and **fixed** vs **small**.

Comment: The point of time complexity is to get some idea of running time versus input size, regardless if the input size is fixed or not. I consider it misleading to state the time complexity to sort two different fixed size but different in size arrays as having time complexity O(1). Take at look at [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Big O notation is used to describe how running time or space grows as the input grows. If the number of things you are sorting doesn't grow as the input grows, then the sorting step of the algorithm you're evaluating is `O(1)`.

Example: Let's say your input is an array of length `n >= 10`, and your output is the same array but with the first 10 elements in sorted order and the rest unchanged. Then, because the time you spend sorting doesn't grow as the input grows (as n gets bigger), the sorting step is O(1).

Comment: Thank you, that is clear. But this means that there can be many "costly" operations that are O(1) in paper. Is there a way to account for those when designing or analyzing algorithms (both in theory and the industry)?

Comment: @SándorDés, ...big-O is not used as a tool for analyzing real-world costs, only for analyzing scaling factors. This question only comes up on account of misapprehension of its purposes. Analyzing real-world costs is what profilers are for -- a tool like [Cachegrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html) will give a better understanding of CPU costs (folded into big-O as constant factors) than any paper analysis.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That makes sense. I often used Valgrind but I didn't know about Cachegrind.

Comment: Time complexity for big O should be the same regardless even when `n` is a constant. For the OP's question, consider the time complexity for sorting two different fixed sized arrays of different sizes, stating that both have time complexity O(1) is misleading. Take a look at [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), which bases the time complexity on the size of the input, even if that input size is fixed. The point of time complexity is to get an idea of running time versus input size.

Answer (score 0):

Any bounded running time is said to be constant, by definition.

For instance, solving the Traveling Salesman problem for a billion cities takes constant time.

This is because the Big-O notation refers to no time unit (no real computer is involved), and any fixed amount is equivalent to 1.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice for you to learn why (as an alternative to following what others are telling you) might be to analyze the complexity of the routine both ways: one where *you* get to define the complexity of sorting 5 elements, and the other, of course, is the given way. Then apply the analysis to a few different input lengths and see which one makes more sense.